# How to log all ports once opened by a process/app in Linux for short time?

Tags: linux, networking, netstat, ports

I have an app that makes some kind of upd ping to the network and for some short time listens for some port in order to receive some feedback during some timeout. It is short enough to observe if with netstat. I need events of opening port and closing it to be logged. Any ideas?

Comment: First thing I'd try is `strace` with the some filtering to get only open and close system calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it is the best approach but i used

```
buffer1=$(ss -ltun); while true; do buffer2=$(ss -ltun); diff <(echo "$buffer1") <(echo "$buffer2") >> netlog2.log; buffer1=$buffer2; done
```

^C

cat netlog2.log 
    6c6
    < tcp    0      8                172.16.1.215:31087                      *:*
    ---

> tcp    0      8                172.16.1.215:47339                      *:*
>       6d5
>       < tcp    0      8                172.16.1.215:47339                      *:*
>       11a11
>   tcp    0      8                172.16.1.215:49491                      *:*
>       11d10
>       < tcp    0      8                172.16.1.215:49491                      *:*
>       10a11
>   tcp    0      8                172.16.1.215:35249                      *:*